# How can I manage my Ubuntu Server from a Windows client?

Tags: networking, server, landscape

I have an Ubuntu Server on a dedicated machine (version 16.04.1), and I have set up a Landscape on premises (https://landscape.canonical.com/set-up-on-prem). Is there a way to manage the Ubuntu Server from my Windows 10 client, similar to Windows version of Server Manager for Windows Server? The idea is to set up a user interface from which I can manage the Ubuntu Server (monitor resources, install software, update software, etc.)

Comment: [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) can do something similar.  Once set up, you access it through a web browser at `https://IP_of_Server:10000`.

Answer (score 1):

With Landscape server you can push updates, remotely execute simple scripts, collect system inventory data (proc, ram, chipset, etc.), and graph basic system performance.  All remotely through a web browser.  No client install required.  Think of it as WSUS on steroids.

If you are looking for true remote management (which is super-overkill for a single host), then you probably want to look at Puppet or other similar tool.  But for one server, that would be harder than just learning a few linux command line tools.